# problema ejercicio con cambo de strings

Tags: python, string

¿qué instrucción me recomiendan para empezar a dar solución al siguiente problema?

*Escriba una función que reciba un string como parámetro y retorne el string, pero con cada elemento que estuviese en mayúsculas reemplazado por "$". Asuma que el string consistirá solamente de letras.
Por ejemplo si el string es "Viva la Vida", entonces tu función debe retornar "$iva la $ida".*

gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Siento comunicarte que es muy poco probable que, escribiendo el enunciado del ejercicio, alguien lo responda haciendo todo el trabajo por ti. Te sugiero que lo leas detenidamente, investigues un poco, intentes hacerlo por ti mismo, y, en caso de no resolverlo, vuelvas exponiendo tu trabajo y explicando dónde tienes el problema. Creo que antes de preguntar deberías haber leído [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Te invito a que lo leas.

Comment: lo mismo que Arg0s pero como es tu primera vez, re la respondere. yo tambien cometi el mismo error hace años.

Comment: @JhonnattanRivera aunque eres nuevo e intentas ayudar (yo también lo hicé). No está bien visto por la comunidad resolver dudas de ejercicios en los que no se presenta ni siquiera una mínima investigación previa ni intentos de hacer dicho ejercicio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ellos puedes usar las siguiente funciones de python `isUpper()` para detectar si es letra  mayúscula y la función `replace()` que recibe dos parámetros, el parámetro actual y el parámetro por el que lo deseas reemplazar.

Recorres  el string con un while incrementando el índice y vas reemplazando cada vez que te encuentras con un `UpperCase`

Teniendo una función definida, puedes volver a usarla cada vez que gustes.

```html
def upperReplace(var):
    string = var
    indice = 0

    while indice < len(string):
        letra = string[indice]
        if letra.isupper() == True:
            string = string.replace(letra, '$')
        indice += 1

    return string


print(upperReplace('CarNaVal')) #output: $ar$a$al
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes comparar usando la funcion ord() que considera las letras con orden

```
input = "Viva la Vida"
replacedValue = "$"
output = ''
for char in input:
  output = output + replacedValue if ord('A') <= ord(char) <= ord('Z') else output + char

print(outpot) //$iva la $ida
```